# SQL Azure Hyperscale

Tags: sql, azure

I wanted to try SQL Azure Hyperscale, after I selected it seems I no longer have the option to move out of it.  If I try, I get this message "databases cannot be moved out of hyperscale tier".

The Copy option is not available and restore does not give you the capability of choosing a different configuration.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question in dba.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is for programming questions, not infrastructure ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration to Hyperscale is currently a one-way operation. Once a database is migrated to Hyperscale, it cannot be migrated directly to a non-Hyperscale service tier. At present, the only way to migrate a database from Hyperscale to non-Hyperscale is to export/import using a BACPAC file or other data movement technologies (Bulk Copy, Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, SSIS, etc.).

The Copy database option is currently not available on Hyperscale, but it will be in Public Preview in the near future.